# Dynamic starting position in substring and dynamic length

Tags: sql, substring, teradata, instr

I have code that for the most part is working as intended. However, it is returning one character too many at the end. I tried adding -1 and I get an out of bounds error. What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT
  SUBSTR(
    t.variable, 
    INSTR(t.variable, '*', 1, 2) + 1, 
    INSTR(t.variable, '*', 1, 3) - INSTR(t.variable, '*', 1, 2)
  ) 
FROM test t;
```

I tried -1, +1. The -1 gives me an outbound error and the +1 adds on an extra character.

Sample value:

```
XBR*jkhehj8f22*3012367134*CVHI*N* X*G*P
```

Comment: No one ever says "a code" when referring to program source code. It's "a snippet of code", or "an excerpt of code", or "a sample of code", or just "code".

Comment: What DBMS are you using? And, first things first, what are you actually trying to do? Get the characters between the 2nd and 3rd occurrence of '*'?

Comment: Looks like Oracle, but I'm not sure. At least, that's the only option where I could get a working fiddle. https://dbfiddle.uk/XHCWl-Fu

Comment: Teradata and use all of the text between the 2nd and 3rd occurrence of the * but without the * at the end

Comment: @Joe I can reproduce that error in Teradata when the string does not have a 3rd occurrence of '*'. Are you sure all records have at least 3 asterisks?

Comment: @Joe Teradata has a function for this though. As long as you aren't on a very old version. `strtok('XBR*jkhehj8f22*3012367134*CVHI*N* X*G*P', '*',3)`

Comment: You need `instr(...) - instr(...) - 1`

Comment: @Error_2646 - it turns out there are some rows where it doesn’t exist and that is what’s causing the error. I tried it with a where clause and it worked. Any tips on it skipping the rows without appropriate data? Many thanks!

Comment: @Joe STRTOK() will handle that for you. You should use STRTOK if you can. A hack would be to concatenate 3 \*'s to the end of the string then do this transformation. That'll return empty string if it reaches your padding. Otherwise you'll need a case expression with a regex replace, i.e. remove all non-*'s characters and check the length. If it's less than 3, then null. Else do the transformation.

Answer (score 1):

Where did you put the `-1`? Put it in the right place and this seems to work:

```
SELECT
  SUBSTR(
    t.variable, 
    INSTR(t.variable, '*', 1, 2) + 1, 
    INSTR(t.variable, '*', 1, 3) - INSTR(t.variable, '*', 1, 2) -1
  ) 
FROM test t;
```

See it here:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/mXkc0JXb

But mostly, my suggestion is to **fix the schema**, because delimited data within a column like this usually really is a **broken** design. This cries out for an additional table with (likely) 9 columns: one for the primary key from this table (and a unique constraint), and one for each of the 8 `*`-delimited fields from this column.

Comment: In the same spot, but Teradata kept giving me and out of bounds error

Comment: I wish I could change the schema but this is for a company in which I have no say in that whatsoever

Comment: Check if it works for the example string (hardcode that string instead of expression) then try with a substring that has less than 3 stars. If it fails, you need to use case expression to handle those cases.